# Move a div on scroll with different position at top and bottom of the scroll

Tags: jquery

I have this website and i want the rocket to land on the moon at the bottom of the page. 
While scrolling it have to follow the website, but on the bottom of the page it has to move down to land on the moon. Anyone got an idea? I tried several things but can't get it fixed.

http://www.websoy.nl/PROMO-WEBSITE/

Comment: Hi Joost, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please put the relevant fragments of the HTML and JavaScript from your web site into the question? Links rot over time and that will render your question useless to future visitors.

Comment: you can look into parallax scrolling

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the onscroll event to change the bomb's position

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #outer {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                overflow: auto;
            }
            #inner {
                height: 3000px;
                width: 1000px;
                position: relative;
            }
            #bomb {
                background-color: black;
                width: 50px;
                height: 50px;
                position: absolute;
                left: 450px;
                top: 30px;
                z-index: 1000;
            }
            #moon {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100px;
                background-color: yellow;
                position: absolute;
                left: 0px;
                top: 2900px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var animaTimer;
            function updatePosition () {
                var outer = document.getElementById('outer'),
                    bomb = document.getElementById('bomb'),
                    top = outer.scrollHeight * (outer.scrollTop / (outer.scrollHeight - outer.clientHeight)) + 30 - 50;
                top = top < 30? 30 : top > 2900? 2900 : top;
                // clear old timer
                if (animaTimer)
                    clearInterval(animaTimer);
                // start move
                moveBomb (bomb, top);
            }
            function moveBomb (bomb, pos) {
                animaTimer = setInterval (function () {
                    // bpos: current position of bomb
                    // mov: the target position
                    var bpos = parseInt (bomb.offsetTop),
                        mov = (pos - bpos) / 6;

                    if (mov <= 2 && mov >= -2) { // only 2px left
                        bomb.style.top = pos + 'px';
                        clearInterval(animaTimer);
                    } else {
                        bomb.style.top = bpos + mov + 'px';
                    }
                }, 50);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="outer" onscroll="updatePosition();">
            <div id="inner">
                <div id="bomb"></div>
                <div id="moon"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i try to achieve, only the animatie isn't smooth. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You can try use a timer to move bomb, or use jquery animate http://api.jquery.com/animate/